# Then () function is not executed in vue store function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

below console message is printed

```
console.log("loadPosts check 11");
console.log("loadPosts check 22");
```

but this is not printed

```
console.log("res : ", res);
```

maybe then() is not excuted
but I don't know reason

```
    loadPosts({ commit, state }, payload) {
        console.log("loadPosts check 1111");
        if (state.hasMorePost) {
            console.log("loadPosts check 2222");
            this.$axios.get(`http://localhost:3085/posts?offset=${state.mainPosts.length}&limit=10`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("res : ", res);
                    commit('loadPosts', res.data);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("err : ", err);
                });
        }
    },
```

if you know reason thanks for let me know
[image]

enter image description here[image: console message]

Comment: If your "then" isn't executing, your catch is, but you have no catch written so you're missing the error. Write the catch - catch((err) => console.log(err)) and then follow that error.

Comment: thanks i tried that before but it's not work no message was printed

Comment: and i update again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `async` and `await` keywords.

```
async loadPosts({ commit, state }, payload) {
        console.log("loadPosts check 1111");
        if (state.hasMorePost) {
            console.log("loadPosts check 2222");
            await this.$axios.get(`http://localhost:3085/posts?offset=${state.mainPosts.length}&limit=10`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("res : ", res);
                    commit('loadPosts', res.data);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("err : ", err);
                });
        }
    },
```

Comment: very thanks but it's not work
i updated =>     this.$axios.get(`http://localhost:3085/posts?offset=${state.mainPosts.length}&limit=10`)

but result is same

Comment: loadPosts 1111 loadPosts 2222 is printed that is all thanks

Comment: Can you check if the request was successful on Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools?

Comment: rcbgalido thanks for answer i updated network tabb image

Comment: https://github.com/hyunsokstar/vue-nodebird-hyun/blob/master/ch2/front/pages/index.vue

Comment: Should loadposts requests show up in the network tab?